# Color code for vi on terminal on Mac?

Tags: terminal, mac

I have been using my school's tux for a while. It was built with nice color code for each syntax for each programming languages. I want to do the same on the machine that I just purchased. When I invoke

```
vi filename
```

The view was plain black and white. How do I customize so that when I view the script/code files on terminal, it will have nice color code? For example, if statement will be read, string will be purple, etc. 
As far as I know, it may have something to do with .profile file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
set term=builtin_ansi
syntax on
```

If you’re using iTerm, use this instead of line 2:

```
set term=xterm-256color
```

Comment: I don't see any vimrc file in my computer. I did ls -a.  do I just create one myself?

Comment: @Fyr Yes, you'll need to create one if you've never needed one before. It will be read automatically when it exists.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. How can I customize specific color?

Comment: Also, after add these three lines. After I enter these 3 lines, when I exit from a file, the file is still remained on the screen. How do I get rid of that?

Answer (score 4):

Use `:syn on` to turn on syntax highlighting. Put this in your `~/.vimrc` file to use it every time. (Vim should detect your terminal type automatically, no need to worry about that.)

To customize the colors, use the `:highlight` command. Type `:help :hi` in Vim for more information on this. For more help on syntax highlighting in general, type `:help :syntax-highlighting`.

If you want to customize it a lot, you can even create a color scheme. This is basically a list of commands, like a .vimrc file, into which you put all the `:hi` commands. Make sure to include `let colors_name = "whatever"` somewhere so it'll work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following codes in `~/.vimrc`

```
syntax on
colorscheme desert
```

After this, the file will not remain on the screen or will not create any scrolling problem. All the available colors can be found in `/usr/share/vim/vim82/colors`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color scheme displayed by vim, you can do as follows:

1. You can find installed color schemes in the following path:
   `/usr/share/vim/vim*/colors/`
2. To use XXX color scheme type the following in vim text editor:
   `:colorscheme XXX` (here `XXX` is the name of a color scheme as listed in the step 1.